# reverseengineering.stackexchange.com is overflowing

Tags: bug, design, advertising

`reverseengineering.stackexchange.com` is a bit, umm... long. The inter-site adverts can't sustain the sheer length of the name any longer!

[image]

Graduated sites get to be advertised by their logos and design, they don't have the site URL obviously there. One possible solution would be to just have the name of the site, rather than the URL for beta sites as well. Or just make the text smaller.

Comment: We should rename to `reveng.se.com` - if you can't figure out what that means, the site isn't for you.

Comment: *"Dear moderator neckbeards, why did you close my perfectly on topic questions on revenge? Your URL indicates such questions are welcome"* @Oded.

Comment: Did you work out what a neckbeard was in the end then @Bart? I'm still not sure...

Comment: Not a clue. But I'll be (ab)using the term whenever I can.

Comment: The URL looks like it fits to me.

Comment: @Bart http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216020/ ;)

Comment: If you zoom in the "m" overlaps the right border @Cole; even if it did fit it doesn't look good. There needs to be more space around the edges.

Comment: @Bart, ben: [This is a neckbeard](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTJPkxJ2qat5vtOU-pmJzbTs3dMAmBh4TCDfazPnrWhkSjKy-1X)

Comment: @Oded I [had suggested](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9/whats-the-elevator-pitch-for-our-site/36#comment71_36) that a long time back. Nobody took it seriously :)

Comment: So this is… * puts on sunglasses * Stack Exchange Overflow?